# Set the value of the select box using cookie value in struts1

Tags: cookies, struts-1, setcookie

Hi friends,

I am trying to set the value of the select box using the cookies value (i want every time same value that i select the first time until i am not made any changes to it).

I am working with the struts1.

Here is my JSP:

```
<html:select property="employee" >
    <html:option value="">--- select one ---</html:option>
    <html:optionsCollection name="empList" value="id" label="name" />
</html:select>
```

and in the action class I have the following:

```
String empStr; // value sent from the form

if (CookieUtils.getCookie(request, "employee") == null) {
    CookieUtils.setCookieValue(response, employee,
                    empStr, 60 * 60);
}else{
   if(empStr!=null && !empStr.equals(""))
     CookieUtils.setCookieValue(response, "employee",
                        empStr, 60 * 60);
   CookieUtils.getCookie(request, "employee");
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of the select box, or the cookie? Your text says one thing, but everything in the code revolves around setting the cookie.

Comment: Hi dave,I am try to set the value of the select box using the cookies.For Ex:- suppose i have a page called page1.jsp on which i have the select tag,now with the help of form action i submit the page and get the value of the select tag inside the action class and set the value in cookies,now what my need is, when i go to the same page is show the same value that i select at the time of form submit.

Comment: Well, you need to show where you set the form value before showing the form, everything here is not that.

Comment: Thanks dave,actually i found the problem inside the form value setting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of debugging the code i found that i miss the struts 1 main property i.e i need to give all the information to the form (set the values that you want on the request). So after setting the values in the action class for the form solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is by using getParameter method of request object. Suppose the name of the checkbox is "mycheckbox" then use following code:
String value = request.getParameter("mycheckbox");